# Alternative to selenium chrome headless

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver, headless

I've written a bit of python code to go to a website, log in and take some screenshots. This works fine in windowed mode, but when i make it headless, it takes significantly longer, some 2-3x longer. Even just identifying elements by xpath which is instant in windowed mode takes 10 seconds in headless mode. I also noticed my CPU fans spin up loudly while in headless mode. I've searched online for others with the same issue, but none of the solutions work, namely adding certain options:

```
options.add_argument('--no-proxy-server')
options.add_argument("--proxy-server='direct://'")
options.add_argument("--proxy-bypass-list=*")
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
```

Does anyone know of other ways to fix the headless performance? Alternatively ive been launching it windowed with location set off screen, which hides it but does steal mouse focus when clicking which is annoying. Is there a way to stop it doing that?

Comment: headless is not stable, what is your requirement ?

Comment: some websites notice the difference between `windowed` and `headless`. Which site(s) are affected or do you see this for all sites ?

Comment: I am accessing reddit